# JQuery Add Class to Unrelated Div On Click

Tags: jquery

I would like to add the class "favourite" to the first div with class "box" above the div with class "click-me" when clicked. But it isn't a parent or related at all.

```
      <div class="box">
          <div>
            <img src="">
          </div>
      </div>


    <div class="modal">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>

              <h2>
                <div class="click-me">
                   Click me
                </div>
               </h2>

             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I have tried:

```
            $(".click-me").click(function () {
                $(this).prevAll('.box:first').addClass('favourite');
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of `closest` and `prev`

```js
$(".click-me").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.modal').prev(".box").addClass('favourite');
});
```

```css
.favourite {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div>
    box
    <img src="">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="modal">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>

          <h2>
            <div class="click-me">
              Click me
            </div>
          </h2>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It'll working:

```
 $(".click-me").click(function () {
          $('.box').first().addClass('favourite');
     });
```